# GL.Rotate and Matrix4.CreateRotationX different ouputs

Tags: opengl, opentk, rotational-matrices, glrotate

I tried to rotate some vertices using different ways of rotation - GL.Rotate, Matrix4.CreateRotationX and Matrix4.RotateX. To my surprise they gave different outputs. 
Here's the function that creates the three matrices and outputs them to the console.

```
    private void for_debug()
    {
        Vector3 CubeRotationAnglesInDeg = new Vector3(15, 29, 84);

        Matrix4 XCubeRotationMatrix1 = Matrix4.CreateRotationX(Helper.ToRadians(CubeRotationAnglesInDeg.X)),
                YCubeRotationMatrix1 = Matrix4.CreateRotationY(Helper.ToRadians(CubeRotationAnglesInDeg.Y)),
                ZCubeRotationMatrix1 = Matrix4.CreateRotationZ(Helper.ToRadians(CubeRotationAnglesInDeg.Z));
        Matrix4 finalMatrixMine1 = XCubeRotationMatrix1 * YCubeRotationMatrix1 * ZCubeRotationMatrix1;


        Matrix4 XCubeRotationMatrix2 = Matrix4.RotateX(Helper.ToRadians(CubeRotationAnglesInDeg.X)),
                YCubeRotationMatrix2 = Matrix4.RotateY(Helper.ToRadians(CubeRotationAnglesInDeg.Y)),
                ZCubeRotationMatrix2 = Matrix4.RotateZ(Helper.ToRadians(CubeRotationAnglesInDeg.Z));
        Matrix4 finalMatrixMine2 = XCubeRotationMatrix2 * YCubeRotationMatrix2 * ZCubeRotationMatrix2;


        GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview);
        GL.LoadIdentity();
        GL.Rotate(CubeRotationAnglesInDeg.X, Vector3.UnitX);
        GL.Rotate(CubeRotationAnglesInDeg.Y, Vector3.UnitY);
        GL.Rotate(CubeRotationAnglesInDeg.Z, Vector3.UnitZ);
        Matrix4 finalMatrixOpen;
        GL.GetFloat(GetPName.ModelviewMatrix, out finalMatrixOpen);

        Console.WriteLine(finalMatrixMine1.Column0);
        Console.WriteLine(finalMatrixMine1.Column1);
        Console.WriteLine(finalMatrixMine1.Column2);
        Console.WriteLine(finalMatrixMine1.Column3);
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine(finalMatrixMine2.Column0);
        Console.WriteLine(finalMatrixMine2.Column1);
        Console.WriteLine(finalMatrixMine2.Column2);
        Console.WriteLine(finalMatrixMine2.Column3);
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine(finalMatrixOpen.Column0);
        Console.WriteLine(finalMatrixOpen.Column1);
        Console.WriteLine(finalMatrixOpen.Column2);
        Console.WriteLine(finalMatrixOpen.Column3);
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

And here's the ToRadians function

```
    public static float ToRadians(float degrees)
    {
        return degrees * (float)(Math.PI / 180f);
    }
```

Is this normal and what can I do to make the results  the same?

Edit:
here's the output

```
(0.09142262, -0.9475183, 0.3063508, 0) 
(0.8698285, 0.2257573, 0.4386708, 0) 
(-0.4848096, 0.2263682, 0.8448178, 0) 
(0, 0, 0, 1) 

(0.09142262, -0.9475183, 0.3063508, 0)
(0.8698285, 0.2257573, 0.4386708, 0)
(-0.4848096, 0.2263682, 0.8448178, 0)
(0, 0, 0, 1)

(0.09142266, -0.8698285, 0.4848096, 0)
(0.9737504, -0.02382383, -0.2263682, 0)
(0.2084515, 0.4927787, 0.8448178, 0)
(0, 0, 0, 1)
```

Comment: Please post the output as well - it will help people who can't/don't want to recreate your sample.

Answer (score 0):

they should make the same, at least the Matrix4.CreateRotationX and Matrix4.RotateX. The definition fo the functions are equal.
here: http://www.opentk.com/files/doc/struct_open_t_k_1_1_matrix4.html#ae9868e1bd3b8aa411abd848e107a55af.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you should put your GL.Rotate() commands in the reverse order to get the desired result.